# Sym link not generated after reboot on mac

Tags: macos, symlink

I used below steps to create symlink on my mac

1. sudo vi /etc/synthetic.conf
2. Add an entry reports    Users/myself/reports, where the empty space is a tab (Ctrl-V + Tab) character.
3. Reboot

After rebooting i am not able to find the symlink.
Any suggestions?